# Is there a default style?

Tags: openlayers

Is there a default style for openlayers features?
I guess, what I really want to ask is, where does the `accuracyFeature` in the geolocation example (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation.html) gets its style from?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It's missing from the version 5 documentation, but you can find it in version 4 https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.style.html

As for where it gets it from, the style function of newly created layers will return that style array

```
var defaultStyles = new ol.layer.Vector().getStyleFunction()();
```